# How do I extract the value before and after the "." as separate values in a folder path string?

Tags: regex

Starting with this string:

```
C:\\folder1\folder2\firstname.lastname\folder3\folder4
```

I need to get the "firstname" and "lastname" values from this string using a RegEx expression.  I do not want the "." to appear in either value.  This is just a RegEx string.  I'm not using it in another programming language.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This did work perfectly in my application, but it turns out that my folder path is different than I previously thought.  My path is actually:  C:\Client Records\last.first.MVA.02.13.1999          Is it possible to stop at the first period and get first and last name as my two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of following capture groups is your expected words :

```
([^\\]*)\.([^\\]*)
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/iS5qG1/1

Comment: Thank you for the help. This did work perfectly in my application, but it turns out that my folder path is different than I previously thought. My path is actually: C:\Client Records\last.first.MVA.02.13.1999 Is it possible to stop at the first period and get first and last name as my two values?

Comment: @JohnDiCarlo So whats your expected output?

Comment: My first value would be "last" and my second value would be "first".

Comment: @JohnDiCarlo You can just put 2 dot in your character class `([^\\.]*)\.([^\\.]*)` https://regex101.com/r/pB7yL4/1

Comment: @JohnDiCarlo Welcome so you can tell this to community by voting and accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\\)([^.\\]+)\.([^.\\]+)(?=\\)
```

Try this.Use group 1 , group 2 to get your value.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/29